# Colouring a $n\times n$ grid with $3$ colours

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Let $n$ be a natural number divisible by $3.$ Let there be a $n\times n$ grid. You have three colours, say red, green, and blue. How many ways are there to colour the grid such that each row has $\frac{n}{3}$ cells of each colour and each column has $\frac{n}{3}$ cells of each colour?

I think I have been able to solve this for the $3\times 3$ case. Each valid permutation of the first row of a $3\times 3$ grid gives rise to two valid colourings of the grid. There are $6$ valid permutations of the first row. So, there are $12$ ways to colour a $3\times 3$ grid such that each row and each column has exactly $\frac{n}{3}$ cells of each colour. Is this right?

I am thinking of generalising this approach to solve the full question. Let $n=3k.$ Then, there are ${{3k}\choose{k}}{{2k}\choose{k}}$ valid permutations of the first row. My thinking is, the number I'm looking for is some integer multiple of this number. I'm thinking something like $n-1,$ (since in the $3\times 3$ case, each valid permutation of the first row gave rise to $3-1$ valid colourings) but I'm not able to prove it. Of course, this is assuming that my approach and answer to the $3\times 3$ case is correct.

How to solve this question?

Possible off-topic question: What is a good way to develop combinatorial intuition? For some reason, I feel like I'm missing a small thing that turns this question from hard to easy. How does one train their brain to think combinatorially?

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @donaastor, a friend of mine asked me this. Not sure where he got it from, though.

Comment: Did you compute the solution for $n=6$ and $n=9$? Maybe it would help spot some pattern?

Comment: @donaastor, I tried to. However, I wasn't able to come up with a systematic way to count. The computation seems too tedious.

Comment: Ok, then I'll do it. Also, 12 is the correct answer for n=3. There is 6 ways for the first row. Then there are 2 ways to complete the first column and after that the rest of the board fills up uniquely.

Comment: @donaastor, yes, that was my reasoning too. The first row fills up in $6$ ways, the second in $2$ and the third in $1.$

Comment: Note that $k!^3{{3k}\choose{k}}{{2k}\choose{k}}=n!$, and any permutation of the columns of a valid solution results in a valid solution. However, for larger $n$ there could be identical columns, so there is no guarantee that the total number of solutions is a multiple of $n!$. I don't see any obvious way to count the solutions, and am not even sure there is a straightforward formula for it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, your comment made me realise that I should actually divide throughout by $k!^3.$ We begin by choosing $k$ cells out of $3k$ and fill this up with one colour. Then, we choose $k$ from the remaining $2k$ cells and fill this up with another colour. This can be done in ${{3k}\choose{k}}{{2k}\choose{k}}$ ways. No need to multiply by $k!^3.$ Am I right in this? I didn't realise this at first since I only used that formula for $k=1.$

Comment: Here is a possible ballpark figure.   Put the rows in independently, which can be done in $(n!/((n/3)!)^3)^n$ ways.  Treat the columns as independent random sets.  Each has a chance of $(n!/((n/3)!)^3)/3^n$ of being correct.  That gives $(n!)^{2n}/((n/3)!)^{6n}/3^{n^2}$.  Using Stirling, that would be about $3^{n^2-n}/(2\pi n)^{2n}$

Comment: That should be $3^{n^2+3n}/(2\pi n)^{2n}$ which is 8.6 for $n=3$

Comment: Note that if you get $n$ rows and $n-1$ columns, you get the last for free.

Comment: Ok, the code is here: https://github.com/donaastor/nxn. If it's correct, then the number for $n=2$ is 65128860, which is already too big. This can't answer $n=3$. I hope this gives some insight.

Comment: @MikeEarnest That is the version `state25`. I get 13185 for that. The full version is `state36`. I don't think that you can just permute rows and columns however you like, some may be the same. That is exactly why I coded both versions.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Oh, I know the bug. I'm gonna fix it now.

Comment: I finished my code. @MikeEarnest, I fixed it. Now I too get the result `35 599 500` for the $6\times6$ table. I still don't understand why it should be divisible by the number you were talking about, even though it is. EDIT: I do now...

Comment: @donaastor, my friend got this question from Quora.

Comment: A slight tweak, still with the random approximation.  First fill the rows, in one of ${n\choose n/3,n/3,n/3}^n$ ways.  Then, separately fill the columns, with the same number of options.  You have a solution if all $n^2$ cells match, one chance in $n^2\choose n^2/3,n^2/3,n^2/3$.  So I expect ${n\choose n/3,n/3,n/3}^{2n}/{n^2\choose n^2/3,n^2/3,n^2/3}$ solutions.  The values for $n=3,6$ and $9$ are $27.8; 83.4$ million and $2.53×10^{21}$.  The first two are about 2.3 times bigger than the correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment, but here is what I could figure out.

I will refer to the three colors as $0,1,$ and $2$.

Let $T_n$ be the number of colorings of a $(3n)\times (3n)$ grid. We know that $T_1=12$.

Let us say that a coloring is "standard" if the first row and column consist of $n$ zeroes, followed by $n$ ones, followed by $n$ twos.
Let $t_n$ be the number of standard colorings. For example, $t_1=1$, because the only standard $3\times 3$ coloring is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2\\1&2&0\\2&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Lemma:** For all $n\ge 1$, $$T_n=t_n\cdot \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}\cdot \frac{(3n-1)!}{(n-1)!\cdot (n!)^2}$$

*Proof:* Note that $\frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}$ gives the number of ways to label the first row with $n$ zeroes, ones, and twos. Then, $\frac{(3n-1)!}{(n-1)!\cdot (n!)^2}$ gives the number of ways to fill out the remaining $3n-1$ entries in the first column. Therefore, to prove the lemma, we just need to give a bijection which takes in a standard coloring, a labeling for the first row, and a labeling for the rest of the first column, and returns an arbitrary coloring.

Let $S$ be a standard coloring, let $R$ be a coloring of the first row, and let $C$ be a coloring of the first column, such that $R$ and $C$ assign the same color to the top left entry. First, permute the columns of $S$ so that the first row of $S$ is colored like $R$. There are multiple ways to this, so to be precise, choose the permutation which preserves the order of any columns with the same topmost entry. Similarly, permute the $3n-1$ rows of $S$ besides the top row, in order to match the column coloring of $C$, while preserving the order of rows with the same leftmost entry. What remains is an arbitrary coloring. Since this process is reversible, this is a bijection. $\square$

This lemma is helpful because standard colorings are easier to enumerate by backtracking. Using this, myself and donaastor found that $t_2=13185$, so $T_2=35599500$. However, finding $t_3$ is beyond the capabilities of my computer.

Neither $``1,13185"$ nor $``1,35599500"$ returns any hits in OEIS. However, the related problem of balanced binary colorings of a $(2n)\times(2n)$ grid has an OEIS entry: https://oeis.org/A058527.

#### Approximation

Let $\Omega$ be the set of ways to color a $(3n)\times (3n)$ matrix with three colors, where we only require all of the rows to be balanced. This means $$|\Omega|=\binom{3n}{n,n,n}^{3n}$$
Now, imagining sampling an element from $\Omega$ uniformly at random, and consider the probability of the event that all columns also happen to be balanced. If we could compute this probability, $p$, exactly, we would be able to compute $T_n$, since $p=T_n/|\Omega|$. I guess that
$$
p\approx \left(\binom{3n}{n,n,n}/3^{3n}\right)^{3n-1}
$$
The reasoning is as follows. For each column index, $i$, let $E_i$ be the event that column number $i$ is balanced. It is exactly true that $P(E_i)=\binom{3n}{n,n,n}/3^{3n}$, because each column is equally likely to be any of the $3^{3n}$ ternary sequences. The events $E_1,\dots,E_{3n}$ are highly dependent. For example, if $E_1,\dots,E_{3n-1}$ all occur, then $E_{3n}$ automatically occurs. However, if we approximate the first $3n-1$ events as being independent, we are led to the value above. This suggests
$$
T_n\approx \binom{3n}{n,n,n}^{6n-1} 3^{-3n(3n-1)}
$$
For example, this gives $T_1\approx 10.6$, which is quite close to $T_1=12$. Next is $T_2\approx 1.524\times 10^7$, which is about $60\%$ smaller than the true value of $T_2=35599500$. However, I cannot quantify the error of this approximation for larger $n$.